# Error in Paho MQTT C Client Library

Tags: c, mqtt

I'm try to publish my data via MQTT in C
and I'm use the sample code of ( Paho MQTT C Client Library link [http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTClient/html/pubsync.html]) but I'm getting some error like

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
D:\work\CB\TEST_RUNNING\hello\main.c|21|undefined reference to `MQTTClient_create'|
D:\work\CB\TEST_RUNNING\hello\main.c|26|undefined reference to `MQTTClient_connect'|
D:\work\CB\TEST_RUNNING\hello\main.c|35|undefined reference to `MQTTClient_publishMessage'|
D:\work\CB\TEST_RUNNING\hello\main.c|39|undefined reference to `MQTTClient_waitForCompletion'|
D:\work\CB\TEST_RUNNING\hello\main.c|41|undefined reference to `MQTTClient_disconnect'|
D:\work\CB\TEST_RUNNING\hello\main.c|42|undefined reference to `MQTTClient_destroy'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 7 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
------------------------------------------------------------
```

help me how to remove it and get my resutls

Comment: I got some solution  of that problem but My connection is getting failed and giving error like [MQTTCLIENT_FAILURE] anyone have any IDEA what is this

Comment: Return code: A generic error code indicating the failure of an MQTT client operation.      anyone having any IDEA what kind of that error and how to remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linker error. The linker cannot resolve dependency to functions mentioned in the output. What you need is to provide path to the library -L option and also provide the library name -l option assuming that you are using gcc. In any case try to find a way to add library to your compilation flow.

Comment: yes I'm using gcc can you explain me how to resolve lonker problem

Comment: You need to find out where the lib is located then you can specify this path in the commando line like gcc -L<path_to_lib> -l<libname> your_files

Comment: Return code: A generic error code indicating the failure of an MQTT client operation. anyone having any IDEA what kind of that error and how to remove it

Answer (score 0):

It is basically a linker error.Include the library name after -l.
Paho c client uses four different libraries.

- paho-mqtt3a - asynchronous MQTTAsync
- paho-mqtt3as - asynchronous with SSL MQTTAsync
- paho-mqtt3c - synchronous  MQTTClient
- paho-mqtt3cs - synchronous with SSL  MQTTClient

Eg: For compiling for synchronous publish code (sync_publish.c):

```
gcc sync_publish.c -lpaho-mqtt3c -o output
```